# MYSQL insert failing - Syntax correct?

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone see anything wrong with this INSERT statement?  This fails for me when used in PHP code. Im using MySql 5.6. dept_id is the primary key.I dont see anything wrong with the syntax but it is failing just the same. Any help would be awesome!

```
    $add_sql = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO `vf_department` (`dept_id`,`descr`,`sub_dept`)VALUES('','$new_desc','$new_sub')") or die("Can not add item.");
```

Comment: Yes, the first thing I see wrong is that you're using the `@` prefix to suppress errors.  If the query is failing and you don't know why, being able to see the error message is your first step.

Comment: primary key can't be null

Comment: 1) Don't suppress the error messages with `@`. 2) Why not use `or die(mysql_error())` to see what the error message is, rather than a default message that doesn't tell you anything useful. 3) Your actual error is likely to be because you're adding a blank string to the primary key

Comment: If `dept_id` is auto-generated, just remove `dept_id` and `''` from your query.

Comment: Since `mysql_xxx` don't generate normal PHP error messages, suppressing errors doesn't have much effect.

Comment: yes i see the biggest mistake you have done 


----------

>[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: For an auto-incremented field, you can supply `NULL` as the value and it will increment it, or just leave that column out entirely.

Comment: @dianuj Good advice, but it won't make a damn bit of difference if the problem is with his SQL syntax.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this is OLD OLD code and I dont want to rewrite the entire app -- just make it work. Thanks for that suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your primary key an auto increment?  If so, you do not need to have it as part of the insert statement.

Comment: Or, leave the AUTO_INCREMENT column in the INSERT statement, and specify the keyword NULL in the VALUES clause as the value to be assigned to the column.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys!!! Most of the answers were partially correct and got me where I needed to be. Thanks very much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ebizzity... if the one column is an auto-increment, leave it out of the insert command, MySQL will generate that for you.  As for all the other comments, I'm surprised nobody mentioned your exposure to SQL injection.

if the values for your $new_desc and/or $new_sub contain single quote, that would offset the balance of your command and make it choke... not to mention would COULD happen with sql injection.  Look into cleansing incoming data and parameterize your calls.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$add_sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `vf_department` (`descr`,`sub_dept`)
          VALUES('$new_desc','$new_sub')") or die(mysql_error());
```